# Receiving SOAP messages from a web-service with SoapUI

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, soapui

I'm sending a SOAP message with SoapUI to a web-service. The XML gets parsed with C# and is then sent back to SoapUI. The problem is that the message is sent back only when the web-service is finished i.e:

```
xmlSoapRequest = /* parse the XML here */
//program ends, message returned
return xmlSoapRequest;
```

Is it possible to write a function that sends the parsed XML back for SoapUI to display before the web-service closes? Something like:

```
public void sendReply(XmlDocument xmlSoapRequest)
    {
        //parse XML here
        //send reply
    }
```

I'm trying to keep a log of the requests and replies so sending the message back when the web-service closes is a no-go. Any help with the sending bit would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm following your question right, you want the C# side to be an asynchronous web service?  Here's a general tutorial:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731177.aspx

If you are manually implementing the web service, you could kick off your XML parsing in its own thread:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx

Although you would have to think about how you wanted to handle errors.

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to acheive is to use a function to send the parsed XML back to SoapUI before the web service closes and then write to a log if the message was succesfully sent or not. I have no clue how to write the function that sends the message. Any tips with that would be welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "before the web service closes".  Have you written a normal web service that receives the request, does something with it, logs whether it succeeded or not, and then returns the result?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to achieve. The web service receives a request, parses the XML, sends a response and finally logs that the message has been sent.

Comment: And why can't you just log the message then send the response?

Comment: Seems like that's the best option for simplicity's sake. Thanks for your input.